Is there a practical example of using non-canonicalized path?
When I asked the manual about the which command, I got this answer:

which  returns  the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be
executed in
the current environment, had its arguments been given as commands in a  strictly
POSIX-conformant  shell. It does this by searching the PATH for executable files
matching the names of the arguments. It does not canonicalize path names.

This is the first time I've heard of "cannonical path". I found a clear definition on stackoverflow
Here. The examples given are as follows

absolute path: C:\abc..\abc\file.txt
canonical path: C:\abc\file.txt

It's not hard to see the difference, but who, in practice, would use the first path instead of the second? What would be the point? In other words, what would be the point of using a path that isn't canonicalized?
PS: I just realized that these two examples are for Windows; perhaps not the best choice for my question.

For me there is one practical example when the path+filename will have noncanonical form.
Let suppose you have two variables A1 and B1. Each of them contain part of the path but second one have relative (to something) path, another have drive and directory:
A1="C:\abc"
B1="..\abc\file.txt"

And to get full path you concatenate them and get
C:\abc\..\abc\file.txt

For Linux would be:
A1="/abc"
B1="../abc/file.txt"
P="$A1"/"$B1"

And the result:
/abc/../abc/file.txt


the first B1 variable has "abs" which should be "abc" but I can't edit a single char

@SamDean, corrected, thank you

It took me a while to figure out what you meant, I'm not used to going up the directory tree, but I finally understood.Thanks.

An issue with canonicalization is the fact that it has a time dependency, when symlinks are involved.
So if the symlink changes, your canonical path might point at the wrong file, while it works just fine with the non-canonical path.

The big thing where a non-canonical path matters is in handling of symlinks and relative paths. Path canonicalization explicitly resolves all indirections in the path, including symlinks (with the special exception of the final part of the path being a dangling symlink), .. entries, . entries, and in theory anything else the OS provides for path indirection (as well as deduplicating adjacent path separators). Depending on what’s doing the canonicalization, it may also properly resolve a relative base for the path to make it absolute as well (this is usually desirable, but not always). This means that a canonical path is a point-in-time snapshot of where the non-canonical path used to generate it points to, but there is not any guarantee that it would be the same at any arbitrary point in the past or future (because it may depend both on any symlinks involved, and possibly on what the current working directory is at the time of path resolution).
For the specific case of which, there is another desirable property of the non-canonical form that it reports: It contains the entry from $PATH where the requested binary was found. This lets you be certain what part of $PATH made a binary available, even if that part of $PATH is relative or includes symlinks.
